# Как в одном mysql запросе в нужной таблице в рандомной строке в определенном столбце увеличить значение на 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как в одном mysql запросе в нужной таблице в рандомной строке в определенном столбце увеличить значение на 1? Я пробовал следующее:

```
UPDATE tbl SET num WHERE id=RAND()=num+1;
```

Но это не работает, как правильно составить запрос?
Еще проблема в том, что id может идти не по порядку, а например так: 1,2,3,5,9...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET field = field + 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: спасибо, это отлично работает